# Como fazer Menu Dropdown com efeito de surgir

Tags: jquery, css, dropdown

```js
$(function () {
 $(".menu2").hide();

 $(".open").stop(true, true).mouseover(function() {  
        $(".menu2").fadeIn(100).animate({ top: '-50' }, 400);
    }); 
  
    $(".open").mouseleave(function() {
      $(".menu2").stop(true, true).fadeTo('fast').animate({ top: '1' }, 100).hide();
    })
});
```

```css
#conteudo{
 width:100%;
 height:300px;
 background:#36C;
 }
.menu{
 width:1365px;
 height:30px;
 background:#F00;
 margin:0px auto;
 }
.menu1{
 width:450px;
 height:30px;
 background:#FFF;
 }
.menu1 li{
 width:150px;
 height:30px;
 background:#FF0;
 list-style:none;
 float:left;
 } 
.menu2{
 width:150px;
 height:90px;
 background:;
 margin-top:50px;
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 }
.menu2 li{
 width:150px;
 height:30px;
 background:#C30;
 top:20px;
 position:relative;
}
.menu2 li:hover{
 width:150px;
 height:30px;
 background:#C60;
 top:20px;
 position:relative;
}
menu1 li ul li .open{
 widht:150px;
 height:500px;
 background:#096;
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteudo">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul class="menu1">
      <li>Teste1</li>
      <li class="open">Teste2
        <ul class="menu2">
          <li>Sub-Teste1</li>
           <li>Sub-Teste2</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Teste3</li>
     </ul>
  </nav>    
</div>
```

Boa noite galera, tudo bem?
Estou procurando uma forma de se fazer o menu dropdown, o funcionamento desse menu é exatamente conforme o link abaixo:
http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/textured-responsive-drop-down-menu.
Gostaria que quando o cursor estivesse em cima do link, o submenu tivesse o efeito de surgir, conforme o exemplo do link.

Comment: Coloque o código do que tentou, mesmo que esteja errado.

Comment: Esse seu link é de um gerador de código do menu que você quer. Embaixo do exemplo tem um link para download de um zip com todo o código necessário para gerar esse menu. É isso que você quer?

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela pronta resposta @bfavaretto.
Isso mesmo, preciso saber como se faz esse menu, eu analisei o código fonte que está disponível para download, mas fiquei um pouco confuso, existe uma forma mais simples de se fazer esse menu?

Comment: Olá @renan, tudo bem?
Como o resultado final não ficou próximo ao que eu esperava, achei melhor não coloca-lo aqui, até porque acredito que estou fazendo errado!
Mas caso prefira posso coloca-lo, oq acha?

Comment: Sim Israel, coloque o código. Mas tente isolar o problema, e mostrar somente as partes que não estão funcionando. Dê uma olhada [nesta página de ajuda](/help/mcve).

Comment: Israel, aquele comentário direcionado ao bfavaretto pode ser feito nos comentários.

Comment: Boa noite @bfavaretto, eu fiz o menu e até então deu certo, o problema que estou tendo agora é que quando passo o cursor muitas vezes e em uma velocidade alta no movimento de colocar e tirar-lo em cima do botão que tem o efeito mouseOver() ele trava.
Coloquei o exemplo do código que fiz acima de minha pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é isto que pretendes. 
Eu costumo usar o menu do bootstrap e tambem se consegue por este efeito. Se preisares de ajuda é só dizer.

```js
$(function () {
 $(".menu2").hide();

 $(".open").stop(true, true).mouseover(function() {  
        $(".menu2").fadeIn(100).animate({ opacity:'1' }, 400);
    }); 
  
    $(".open").mouseleave(function() {
      $(".menu2").stop(true, true).fadeTo('fast').animate({ opacity: '0' }, 100).hide();
    })
});
```

```css
#conteudo{
 width:100%;
 height:300px;
 background:#36C;
 }
.menu{
 width:1365px;
 height:30px;
 background:#F00;
 margin:0px auto;
 }
.menu1{
 width:450px;
 height:30px;
 background:#FFF;
 }
.menu1 li{
 width:150px;
 height:30px;
 background:#FF0;
 list-style:none;
 float:left;
 } 
.menu2{
 width:150px;
 height:90px;
 background:;
    opacity:0;
 position:relative;
 display:block;
-webkit-animation: KEYFRAME-NAME 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation:    KEYFRAME-NAME 5s infinite;
  -o-animation:      KEYFRAME-NAME 5s infinite;
  animation:         KEYFRAME-NAME 5s infinite;
 }
.menu2 li{
 width:150px;
 height:30px;
 background:#C30;
 top:20px;
 position:relative;
}
.menu2 li:hover{
 width:150px;
 height:30px;
 background:#C60;
 top:20px;
 position:relative;
}
menu1 li ul li .open{
 widht:150px;
 height:500px;
 background:#096;
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteudo">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul class="menu1">
      <li>Teste1</li>
      <li class="open">Teste2
        <ul class="menu2">
          <li>Sub-Teste1</li>
           <li>Sub-Teste2</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Teste3</li>
     </ul>
  </nav>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Israel, eu não entendi bem qual o propósito do seu menu, se é somente para estudar CSS e jquery ou se vc vai realmente desenvolver uma aplicação.

Se for o segundo caso, eu sugiro usar Bootstarp para economizar seu tempo de desenvolvimento. Se for o primeiro caso, eu sugiro usar [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) para vc usar seu tempo de estudo em uma ferramenta profissional, e que já foi feita para se adptar a dispositivos móveis, celular, tablets etc.

Essa biblioteca é muito fácil e já faz todo o trabalho para vc. Não precisa gastar o seu tempo de desenvolvedor na parte de comportamentos e desenho de objetos pois tudo já está pronto, basta copiar e colar. Existe uma versão do site em [português](http://getbootstrap.com.br/), mas eu não sei se a tradução ja está completa.
No próprio site do Bootstrap vc já vai encontrar muita coisa, muitos tipos de menus. Mas se vc não estiver satisfeito, pode ir no site do [Bootsnip](http://bootsnipp.com/search?q=menu&page=3) e procurar pelo objeto que te interessa, nesse caso, **menu**. Lá vc vai encontrar uma variedade enorme de menus. Se vc quiser aprender Bootstrap e exatamente com o menu da sua questão eu te sugiro o site do [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp).

Fiz 2 exemplos de dropdown:

```
//HTML
    <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nivel 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li>
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


//Js jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Vc trabalha basicamente com HTML, o mínimo de javascript e praticamente zero de css . Usa os atributos de Bootstrap e pronto. Seu menu estrá fumcionando.
Veja o exemplo que criei aqui nesse [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jqg1uaag/2/).